# Proper Type Hints For Generic Type Classes

Tags: python, type-hinting

I am trying to write a tree node class in Python. I have a base class called `Node` that defines the tree semantics and subclasses implementing nodes that contain different kinds of content. I want to use type hints.

Here is a minimal implementation that creates trees of either strings or integers and enumerates them depth-first.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, List, Iterable

T = TypeVar("T")


class Node(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, content: T):
        self.content = content
        self.children: List[Node[T]] = []

    def depth_first_search(self) -> Iterable["Node[T]"]:
        yield self
        for child in self.children:
            yield from child.depth_first_search()


class StringNode(Node[str]):
    def get_string(self) -> str:
        return self.content


class IntegerNode(Node[int]):
    def get_integer(self) -> int:
        return self.content


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = StringNode("apple")
    b = StringNode("banana")
    c = StringNode("pear")
    a.children = [b, c]
    for n in a.depth_first_search():
        print(n.get_string())

    a = IntegerNode(1)
    b = IntegerNode(2)
    c = IntegerNode(3)
    a.children = [b, c]
    for n in a.depth_first_search():
        print(n.get_integer())
```

This code works at runtime, however, from PyCharm I get the warnings "Unresolved attribute reference 'get_string' for class 'Node'" and "Unresolved attribute reference 'get_integer' for class 'Node'" for the `n.get_string()` and `n.get_integer()` lines, respectively.

I have tried specifying various `covariant` and `contravariant` modifiers to the type variable `T`. In Python 3.7 I have also tried using [PEP 563](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#whatsnew37-pep563) by adding `from __future__ import annotations` and removing the quotes from the return value hint for `Node.depth_first_search`. None of this has had an effect.

I have tried creating "type cast" methods like the following in `StringNode`.

```
    def depth_first_search(self) -> Iterable[StringNode]:
        return super().depth_first_search()
```

This takes care of the warning down in the `__main__` block but now I get a "Expected type 'Iterable[StringNode]', got 'Iterable[Node]' instead" warning on the return value of this method.

How do I rewrite the type hints so that I don't get warnings?

Comment: Yes. Also having the type hint on the instance variable has no effect.

Comment: Because your `depth_first_search(self)` always returns an iterator of Node objects. Just access content directly there's no point in having a generic class to create subclasses just to have subclass specific accessors... And no need for those subclasses

Comment: IOW `Node[str]` is not the same as `StringNode`

Comment: In this simple example the subclasses seem excessive but in my real larger application organizing things this way is helpful.

Comment: Essentially, `n` is of type `Node[str]`. Either you cast `n` to `StringNode` or you create a new function `depth_first_search` inside `StringNode` with the correct return type.

Comment: I figured that the problem is that `n` is of type `Node`. What I want to say in the definition of `Node` is "depth first search returns Nodes whose content is the sort specified in the generic variable". I can do this with C++ generics, so I figured there must be a way to do it in Python too, and I just don't know the syntax.

Comment: Another way of asking this question: is there some way I can tell Python's type hinting that I intend `Node[str]` and `StringNode` to be the same thing?

Comment: "I figured that the problem is that n is of type Node. What I want to say in the definition of Node is "depth first search returns Nodes whose content is the sort specified in the generic variable"." *That is what you are doing already*. That's not the problem. The problem is that `Node` objects don't have that method. Now you could use a typevar bound to `Node` and make the iterator return that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way to use Python's type hinting to get the result I want if I make `Node` a base class. However, I can make it work by changing `Node` to a mixin.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Iterable, Generic

T = TypeVar("T")


class NodeMixin(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, *children: T):
        self.children = children

    def depth_first_search(self) -> Iterable[T]:
        yield self
        for child in self.children:
            yield from child.depth_first_search()


class StringNode(NodeMixin["StringNode"]):
    def __init__(self, content: str, *children: T):
        super().__init__(*children)
        self.content = content

    def upper(self) -> str:
        return self.content.upper()


class IntegerNode(NodeMixin["IntegerNode"]):
    def __init__(self, content: int, *children: T):
        super().__init__(*children)
        self.content = content

    def add_five(self) -> int:
        return self.content + 5


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = StringNode("apple", StringNode("banana"), StringNode("pear"))
    for n in t.depth_first_search():
        print(n.upper())

    t = IntegerNode(1, IntegerNode(2), IntegerNode(3))
    for n in t.depth_first_search():
        print(n.add_five())
```

This runs correctly and PyCharm gives me no warnings. Furthermore, I do get warnings if I incorrectly try to call `upper` or `add_five` on the wrong type of object returned by `NodeMixin.depth_first_search`.

Answer (score 2):

When `a` is a `StringNode`, `a.depth_first_search()` returns `Iterable[Node[str]]`, not `Iterable[StringNode]`.

In this case, you probably shouldn't have those `get_string` and `get_integer` methods. Just have clients access `content` directly, or if you're determined to have a getter for some reason, make it `get_content(self) -> T` in the `Node` base class.

I don't think Python's type annotations support having your `depth_first_search` return an iterable of the subclass type you want, without explicit casts or `Any`. You would need to be able to express the fact that `self` has the same type as the elements of `self.children`, and I don't see a way to do that.